# MySQL count changes in sequence

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to find a way to count the number of times a value changes in an ordered list.  Given a sequence such as `A, B, A, A, B, C, C`, there would be 4 changes, ignoring the first one.

What I need is something like a `COUNT(GROUP BY x)` command to be applied after an `ORDER BY y`, but this isn't valid syntax.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this in pure MySQL, or am I better off iterating through with Python?

The table would be sorted by a date field.  For example:

```
+------------+-------+
| Date       | Value |
+------------+-------+
| 2015-09-01 | A     |
| 2015-09-02 | B     | (change)
| 2015-09-03 | A     | (change)
| 2015-09-05 | A     |
| 2015-09-06 | B     | (change)
| 2015-09-07 | C     | (change)
| 2015-09-08 | C     |
+------------+-------+
```

Comment: a sequence implies an order. is there an id or ordered field that determines this sequence. also add the full table definition

Comment: it can be done entirely with mysql. But as @amdixon stated ↑ you need to show more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plan**

> - order by Date
> - calculate lag variable over the ordering
> - calculate changes ( comparing to lag variable )
> - take max(changes) and subtract one for ( for the first transition.. )

**query**

```
set @chgs := 0;
set @lag  := null;

select max(chgs) - 1 as num_changes
from
(
  select `Date`, `Value`,
  @chgs := if(@lag = `Value`, @chgs, 
                if(@lag := `Value`, @chgs + 1, @chgs + 1)) as chgs
  from sequence
  order by `Date`
) calc
;
```

**output**

```
+-------------+
| num_changes |
+-------------+
|           4 |
+-------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e8e6/1)